# Error when using pointer to derivative class as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have encountered a problem when giving as a template pointer argument a pointer to the derivative class instead of the base class. E.i. the following code:

```
class First{};
class Second : public First {};

template<First* ptr> class Third {};

Second obj;

int main(){
    Third<&obj> obj2;
}
```

when compiled returns error:

```
error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'Second *' to 'First *'
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem? I know, I could pass the pointer as an argument in the constructor of `Third` instead of its template argument, but I'd like to differentiate objects of class `Third` with different pointers at the moment of compilation, so that one could only use objects of `Third` with pointers appropriate in the given context.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? o.O

Comment: Class `First` has some non-static fields I need to use when creating an object of `Third` and a method that takes `Third` as an argument, but the method should only work, if the `First` object used to create the `Third` object is the one of which the method is called. I wanted to avoid a situation when one uses objects that don't match, but I guess its not the proper way to do so.

Comment: I don't really understand the down-votes. This is a fair question, with some code exemplification. I'm pretty sure all of us bumped into issues like this before.

Comment: No, I don't understand them either.

Comment: @pahoe, you probably know why using `&obj` as template parameter doesn't work. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. The additional description in the comment is not clear enough for me.

Comment: Thank you all for help. Actually, I'm implementig matrix algebra, with vectors represented in various bases. So, using the notation from the example code: the vector is represented by the class `Third`, and `First` is a class representing vector basis. As multiplying matrix*vector will only give a proper result when both matrix and vector are in the same basis, I wanted to store pointer to basis in vector template argument list, so that the compiler would automatically reject any illigal multiplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit type conversion going on on template type deduction, so your example fails to compile.

Related: [C++ Templates type casting with derivates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500653/c-templates-type-casting-with-derivates)

In non-template code, everything is OK, e.g.

```
First *p = &obj;
```

works just fine.

Your example has the same flavour as

```
template <int N>
void f(){}

int main()
{
    f<42.42>(); // fails, double is not converted to int here
}
```

> error: conversion from 'double' to 'int' not considered for non-type template argument