# Cast boost::shared_array<char> to boost::shared_array<const char>

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, casting

How can I cast a `boost::shared_array<char>` to `boost::shared_array<const char>`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `shared_array` has no `add_ref` method you could emulate it as follows:

```
struct MagicDeleter {
  MagicDeleter( boost::shared_array<char> ptr ) : ptr(ptr) {};
  template<typename T> void operator()(T*) {} 
protected:
  boost::shared_array<char> ptr;
};

...

boost::shared_array<char> orig_ptr( some_val );
boost::shared_array<const char> new_ptr( orig_ptr.get(), MagicDeleter(orig_ptr) );
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, you can't and you shouldn't.

Besides, are you sure you want a `boost::shared_array<const char>` and not a `const boost::shared_array<char>`?

Practically, this works:

```
boost::shared_array<char> acz;
boost::shared_array<const char>& acz2 = reinterpret_cast< boost::shared_array<const char>& >(acz);
```

BUT it is not a good idea and only works if boost::shared_array and boost::shared_array have the same implementation. Templates can be partially specialized:

```
template<class T>
struct TwoImplementations {
    int m_nIntMember;
};

template<>
struct TwoImplementations< const T > {
    double m_fDoubleMember;
};
```

Doing a reinterpret cast between `TwoImplementations<int>` and `TwoImplementations<const int>` is just wrong.

Comment: Never use such a reinterpret_cast, especially in this case! Generally speaking, reinterpret_cast is 99% not portable.

Comment: I know that and acknowledge it in my post. So please don't downvote. It is a language feature, it can work and in 1% of the cases may even be useful.

Comment: @rmn: One size does not fit all, I agree that in this place it's a bad idea, but never say never.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

As both types are based on a template, both types are completely different for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. In case you really need it though, you can create a custom smart-pointer class. Hints for that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639248/c-covariant-templates).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the get() method to get the underlying char*, which is auto convertible to a const char* - but don't assign it to another shared_array because then you'll have the data deleted twice. Just use it as you need it.

like this:

```
boost::shared_array<char> x(new int[13]);
const char *y = x.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have thought of this without Kirill's awesome answer, but you can effectively extend boost's `static_pointer_cast` that is used for `shared_ptr`s to work on `shared_array`s as so:

```
template<typename OriginalType>
struct SharedPtrCastHelper
{
  public:
    SharedPtrCastHelper( const OriginalType & ptr ) : ptr(ptr) {};
    template<typename T> void operator()(T*) {}

  protected:
    OriginalType ptr;
};


template<typename OutT, typename InT>
boost::shared_array<OutT> 
static_pointer_cast( const boost::shared_array<InT> & inSharedPtr )
{
  typedef SharedPtrCastHelper<boost::shared_array<InT> >  Helper;

  return boost::shared_array<OutT>( (OutT*)inSharedPtr.get(), 
                                    Helper(inSharedPtr) );
}
```

with that you can then do something like:

```
boost::shared_array<int>          intArrayPtr( new int[40] );  
boost::shared_array<unsigned int> uintArrayPtr;

uintArrayPtr = static_pointer_cast<unsigned int>( intArrayPtr );
```

Answer (score 0):

Such compiler-generated casting can not be possible.

The internals of the class with const-qualified template parameter may differ dramatically from the class without one, due to template specialization feature.

Moreover, the use of such feature is sometimes a background for compile-time checks that merely may not allow instantiation of `A<const T>` type for every case where `A<T>` type is correct.

Comment: Not possible? Yet boost::shared_ptr supports implicit conversion from derived to base types (and non-const to const) and all sorts of casts.

Comment: It indeed does support *conversion*.  But it can't be *type-casted*.

Comment: It does support casts, unless you mean something else entirely. E.g., `boost::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr(boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_shared_ptr));`